# overflow-y:scroll is not working for chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am not getting a scroll-bar for box in chrome but getting in fire fox and internet explorer

```
li.box{
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding:0;
    border: solid 1px #8c8d8e;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
```

this is JSFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/wydsf2vk/

Comment: can you provide us with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: can you plz put a http://jsfiddle.net so we can fix it for u

Comment: thanks for reply , this is working in jsfiddle but i my project this is not working

Comment: your using chrome while on jsfiddle ?

Comment: hi i have updated  jsfiddle link can you please check its not working in js fiddle also

Comment: In your jsfiddle you've set overflow:hidden so what would you expect. You don't set overflow-y anywhere in the fiddle

Comment: You have used overflow: hidden;

Comment: your actual css part is not included in fiddle, also post latest version link

Comment: Check this fiddle overflow-y:scroll; works http://jsfiddle.net/4Fpq2/176/

Comment: He is correct, overflow-y doesn't work with "-webkit-column-width" but it does after you remove the prefixed one. (Chrome 37) Seems like a browser bug?

Answer (score 6):

Add height property to your css class, to display scrollbar you need to set fix height of your div.

Answer (score 3):

Are you by chance using a track pad instead of a mouse, on OSX?  There's some quirk where the scrollbar will be hidden if you're using a track pad.  Plug in a mouse and see if it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Set max-height for that .box it will work

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `height` CSS property. check snippet below.

```css
.box {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding:0;
    border: solid 1px #8c8d8e;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p> Hello World 1 </p>
  <p> Hello World 2 </p>
  <p> Hello World 3 </p>
  <p> Hello World 4 </p>
  <p> Hello World 5 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your fiddle, that's happening because you've not added the `overflow-y: scroll;` property to the fiddle. It does work for my version (Chrome too).

http://jsfiddle.net/y8jqsya4/

Comment: @AKG I am using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit) for RPM-based Linux, and both your fiddle (wydsf2vk) and Anshuman's display a scroll bar in my browser.

Comment: @AKG note, however, that in yours, the scrollbar is non-functional -- since you did not specify a height, the div automatically expands to fill the contents and will never overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is an OLD issue, but I am posting the workaround if its the Trackpad causing your scroll bar to disappear, try the following:

Go to System Preferences.
Search for 'Show Scroll Bars'
Choose Always.

Answer (score -1):

change your css:-

```
height:100px 
border-radius: 0px;
padding:0;
border: solid 1px #8c8d8e;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.85;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wydsf2vk/2/